# How to migrate KeyStore and Keychain key-value pairs generated by and old Cordova-based App to a new React Native based App?

Tags: react-native, cordova, migration, keystore, keychain

The scenario is quite simple: there is an old App written using Cordova that has to be updated with a new App written from scratch using React Native.

I am not the developer and the maintainer of the App written using Cordova but I could put hands on its source code. I have to rewrite the App and to make a "silently" update, i.e. the new App must no "reset" the data stored on KeyStore (Android) and Keychain (iOS) and it must reuse these data.

When I "update" the App on my test devices I try to access the data generated by the old App using:

- [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain)
- [react-native-secure-key-store](https://github.com/pradeep1991singh/react-native-secure-key-store#readme)

and try to fetch the data, but with no success. The problem is the same on iOS and on Android.

Focussing for the moment on iOS, I use Xcode to build both the Apps. Firstly I build the old version of the App, generate the data and store them on Keychain. Then, I build the new App version, superseding the previous one. I have ensured that on Xcode the **Bundle Identifier** and the **Signing Certificate** is the same for both versions. But from the new version of the App I am still unable to access the Keychain. To make the litmus test: I *downgrade* the App re-building the old version another time, so the old app replaces the new one and in this case from the old App I am able to access the Keychain data.

I am suspecting that, even if the **Bundle Identifier**, the two Apps are using two different Keychain *zones*. So, what I have to do in order to be able to access the data stored by the old app from the new one?

The idea I that the user shouldn't be affected by the update of the App, so the Keychain (and the KeyStore) of the old app must be re-used by the new app.

Note: I see that on the old App, the function used to store data in Keychain/KeyStore is:

```
var ss = new cordova.plugins.SecureStorage(callback)
```

Note: I have already read [this from Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps), but I suppose it could be not my case, because I can't set the Keychain sharing on the old App, since we are not permitted to release an update of the Cordova-base App. But, however we tried *internally* to use Sharing Access without success.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS in particular, keychain access is not just tied to the Bundle ID and signing certificate for the app. There is a third element called the "Groups Entitlement" that is designed to allow multiple applications from the same vendor to share keychain access to the same data (imagine separate email and calendar apps sharing a user's login data). Documentation for this mechanism begins here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps

The documentation is fairly dense, but despite being intended for multiple apps to share data this also controls an application reading its OWN data. You must ensure that your parameters match the old app precisely or you will not be able to read the old values. You didn't provide the code for the old or new apps, but as an example if the old app had stored values in the Keychain on iOS, you might use `react-native-keychain` and the following code to read it:

```
// The "access group" is the Team ID of the OLD APP followed by its full Bundle ID
const accessGroup = 'A12BC3D45.com.company.BundleId';

const accessOptions = {
    accessGroup,
    accessible: Keychain.ACCESSIBLE.AFTER_FIRST_UNLOCK,
};

const oldCreds = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
console.debug('Found old credentials', oldCreds); // REMOVE AFTER DEBUGGING
```

`react-native-keychain` has several load functions and you may need to experiment with others (such as `getInternetCredentials`) if your old app stored things differently.